# How to order items from Room database by date with "MMM dd yyyy" format

Tags: android-room

I'm trying to order items by date from Room database, where the dates are stored as strings with this format `MMM dd yyyy`. Is there any way I could do this without changing structure of my database?

I tried `@Query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date")` which just orders the months alphabetically.

Comment: Did you find any way ?

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my issue by changing my date format to from `Jan 01 2019` to this format `2019 01, 01` and when retrieving from database, I order by the new date format.

**NOTE:** This might not be the best solution but it worked perfectly for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: can you see my question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181364/how-to-order-room-results-by-date-as-string)

Comment: Don't you have same problem?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're facing?

Comment: If month has two digits come at first in sort

Comment: try taking out the `asc` from the query, might still not work but still.

Comment: I found a solution , maybe help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181364/how-to-order-room-results-by-date-as-string/58203956#58203956)