# How to Order Room results by Date as String

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, date-conversion, android-database

I have a `room database`. I have a column for `date` and it's saved as `string`.

I used this `query` for sort my column :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM session WHERE class_id = :classId ORDER BY session_date ASC")
List<SessionEntry> getAllSessions(int classId);
```

**Result :**

```
    1398/11/25
    1398/11/29
    1398/12/5
    1398/2/14
    1398/4/25
    1398/6/17
    1398/6/30
    1398/7/9
    1398/9/14
```

but i want to sort like this :

```
    1398/2/14
    1398/4/25
    1398/6/17
    1398/6/30
    1398/7/9
    1398/9/14
    1398/11/25
    1398/11/29 
    1398/12/5
```

Is there any way I could order by Date as String without modifying the database structure ?

Comment: Use timestamp to save the date cause it will easy to sort it.

Comment: Is possible to change the format of your date column into yyyy-MM-dd i.e. with the month and day always on two digits ?

Comment: in which formate do you have date ?

Comment: Check [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-time-2b4cf9672b98).

Comment: Please try this: @Query("SELECT * FROM session WHERE class_id = :classId ORDER BY (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(session_date, '/', 2), '/', 1)) ASC")

Comment: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: SUBSTRING_INDEX)  @Dhaval Solanki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution but it's not best.

This way is for when you can't change your `Date Column` from String to another type

```
List<SessionEntry> sessionEntries = mDb.sessionDao().getAllSessions(classId);
Collections.sort(sessionEntries, comparing(SessionEntry::convertStringToDate));
```

**Session Entry :**

```
public class SessionEntry {
    .
    .
    .
    public Date convertStringToDate() {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(getSessionDate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me as well. I have date column as string.

Answer (score 1):

in my case it is working as I have like float type formate :

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM growthlogdata WHERE babyid = :childid Order By CAST(dateGrowth AS FLOAT) ASC")
List<SessionEntry> getAllSessions(int classId);
```

Comment: it is yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: you need to take dates in float formate and save it and you can display in  yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: you cant short dates in String formate as you are doing I had the same issue as you

Answer (score 1):

First answer, don’t store dates as strings, use a proper date datatype.

However, if I understand correctly that your SQLite database hasn’t got a date datatype, @matdev is correct: The best solution is to change the format into `yyyy-mm-dd`. This conforms with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and will sort chronologically.